# How does Mirror work in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, mirror

I am stumped. I cannot figure out how to get this thing to work. I saw one answer here that said something about moving the mesh off the object's center point, but it looks to me like the mesh is nowhere near the object's origin when I try to use the Mirror function.

Steps: (1) Open new general file, with basic cube already formed. (2) Tab into Edit mode. (3) Use the Move/Grab tool to shift the cube's mesh off the global origin in X and Y directions. It looks to me like the object's origin (orange dot) remains at the global origin. (3) Select Mesh -- Mirror -- X Global (or Y Global or X Local or Interactive Mode or ANY of the possible subselections for the Mirror function). Result: Nothing. Nothing. And more nothing. Nothing happens. How does this thing work?

I read the online manual. No help there, as usual.

Oh, and when I change the pivot point to 3D cursor and then try the Mirror command, instead of creating a duplicate or copy of the cube mesh in the mirror position, it simply MOVES the cube mesh to the mirror position.

I don't get it.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you're trying to do, what mirror are you refering to? Mirror is a modifier, maybe you're talking about the symmetry options? please show a screenshot

Comment: Yes, there is a Mirror Modifier, one that operates in Object Mode and, unless I misunderstand, affects an entire mesh object. But there is also a Mirror command, available under the Mesh menu in Edit Mode that -- I have reason to believe -- operates only on selected parts of a mesh. That's the one I can't get to work.

Comment: The Mirror you're talking about allow you to flip the mesh, same as SX-1, it won't mirror as the Mirror modifier or as the Symmetrize operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I understand now. I was mistaken about the purpose of the Edit Mode/Mesh/Mirror function.

I've reread the section of the book I'm trying to learn from ("Blender 3D by Example") and I now see that the instructions actually did intend for the mesh object I was trying to mirror be a separate mesh object from the rest of the object I was modeling, and that it did intend for the mirroring to be accomplished using a Mirror Modifier. I was under the mistaken idea that I was supposed to do the mirroring some other way without leaving Edit Mode.

I also reread the online manual about the Mirror command section again and I finally understand. I actually did get it to function as intended: its purpose is to transform a selected mesh into its mirror image. It is not intended to create a mirrored COPY of the mesh. I was able to get it to work; I just didn't know that that was "all" it did.

Answer (score -1):

Open new general scene.

Select the *Cube*, go to *Modifier* panel, click on *Mirror* modifier. Click on axis want to mirror, say X axis.

Click on Cube and switch to *Edit Mode*.

Using *Face Section*, click on face on right side of cube and press  <kbd>G</kbd> for grab, pull to the right or  <kbd>E</kbd> for extrude and pull to right. The left side of cube will copy your actions. Switch to Y or Z axis to do the same on those axis's.

To mirror another way with *Mirror Modifier*. Select on cube in *Object Mode* and move to the right of center lines/ Origin intersection. Place cursor at origin, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>. Then with the cube selected. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> again to place cube's *Origin to Cursor*. Now you got two separate cubes and whatever you do to original cube will be mirror on second cube.

Comment: Granted, but I'm trying to do mirroring on just a part of the mesh object, not the entire thing, which is what the Mirror Modifier will do. There is a command under the Mesh menu in Edit Mode (a Mirror Modifier is applied in Object Mode) that is labeled "Mirror." I am under the impression that it does similar functions as a Mirror Modifier, but only to a selected portion of the mesh. I could be wrong about that. I can't get it to do much of anything.

Comment: @Smith_USA_MD the edit mode Mirror operator is essentially the same as selecting all the geometry you want to run it on and then pressing "S> {axis x,y,z} > -1" to flip the geo. It will only work with the geometry you have selected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).